# Why unsend email is not possible in technical explanation?

Tags: email, smtp, mail-server

I really want to know why does sent email cant be unsend

1. Is it because after mail reach the recipient MTA our Mail Server does not have control/permission to that MTA so it is not possible to unsend it?
2. Or is it because in the recipient SMTP Server has downloaded the sender mail, so it will always available in the recipient SMTP Server after get sent?

or what cause that ?

and if the cause is point number 1, my question what if the Mail Server is the same as mine or in other words for example me and the recipient use gmail

thank you for helping me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason might surprise you but it's rather simple. Because time is linear and you can't travel back in time.

Now, if both you(the sender) and someone else(the receiver) have Microsoft Outlook AND your email accounts are hosted in a Microsoft Exchange Server, then:

1. Open the **Sent Items** folder, and double-click to open the email you want to recall.
2. In the Message window, please click **Message > Actions > Recall This Message**. See screenshot:

[image: image1]

3. In the popping out Recall This Message dialog box, please check the **Delete unread copies of this message** option, and click the **OK** button. See screenshot:
   **Note**: It’s optional to check the **Tell me if recall succeeds or fails for each recipient** option.

[image: image2]

If your recipients **have not read the specified email yet**, this email will be deleted from their Outlook automatically.